# two consequtive rewrite rules not working in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

this is my `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
<FilesMatch “.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$”>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin “domain.com”
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^[A-Za-z-]+/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  viewpost.php?id=$1   [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule   ^[A-Za-z-]+/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  category.php?id=$1   [QSA,NC,L]
```

Except that the first rewrite rule works and the second doesn't.

Comment: i dont know what i am missing.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you've used the flag [L] at the end of your first `RewriteRule`.

> The [L] flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set. In
>   most contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no further rules
>   will be processed. This corresponds to the last command in Perl, or
>   the break command in C. Use this flag to indicate that the current
>   rule should be applied immediately without considering further rules.

Documentation on [Rewrite Flags](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html).

Comment: even after removing L the second part does not get processed. What to do now??